# ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH on images load

Tags: php, ssl, https, get

I was looking other similar posts but I'm still not able to identify the problem.

I have a page with a list of images: https://www.youfurniture.net/news

When the page is loading, many images returns this error:

```
GET https://...(image url) net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

Everything was working fine until I implemented the SSL certificate and switched to https protocol. I tried then to switch back to http and this issue disappear.

I also saved again all the images and uploaded again to be sure that they were not corrupted.

I already contacted my hosting provider, they say that on server side everything is ok.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Within what are you seeing the errors?

Comment: The error is generated by the images in the #ajax_content div, and it is displayed in the browser console (Chrome)

Comment: No errors for me (chrome 44b) or in FF - are you behind a proxy/corp appliance?

Comment: No, but I tried on two different location and I got it on both (with the same internet provider, Fastweb)... Sometimes I don't get this error on the first loading, but I get it when I keep on loading more images